# Multiple dex files when using addtional.jar and httpmime-4.2.5.jar

Tags: android

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/harmony/awt/internal/nls/Messages
```

I got this error when i add `mail.jar`,`activation.jar` and `additional.jar`. I also have `Httpmime.jar` in My project. But when i remove additional.jar from project project error disappear.I clean lots of time my project ,Remove library and rebuild but dose not help.

Comment: In your project directory locate Bin folder, in which there will be one dexedLibs folder. You'll see multiple JARs there. Delete similar ones and try again

Comment: Hey Dhaval ihave:activation-be84067a204345087acf4b726b10aec6.jar
additionnal-321a93f33ff521e34b6da8151a78fcc0.jar
android-support-v4-282b34b60284d4841c847fd80e43021f.jar
annotations-d6a50d4d2b9f8e0b0a3610f56c3df3cc.jar
droidText.0.2-5b510c7b3ae199f832936d31e567ab30.jar
httpclient-4.0.1-3e50fe601cb78d3f0298779ce3ad33e9.jar
httpmime-4.2.5-d7a72483749db52da84ffa1c45f7c8f9.jar
mail-002b75f1550c8044b15f0ee29a432c0a.jar  in my dexedLibs folder which one i have to remove

Comment: Are you using any library projects added to your project?

Comment: shylendra: No brother, i think its causing because of addtional.jar and httpmime.jar ,but i dont know how to resolve it